# iOS PDFKit - setting permissions of the document - is it possible

Tags: ios, user-permissions, ios-pdfkit

Apple's PDFKit allows getting Permission Properties of the PDFDocument. But is there a way to set these permissions as well?

I would like to be able to limit the permissions to "view and print" only.

Thanks
Libor